# Any luck with photo2shape?

Tags: qgis, geotag

I have had variable success with photo2shape in QGIS. I can't figure out what is the success/no success prerequisites. Any thoughts?
Currently I have a directory with all 334 photos having geotag data. QGIS stalls when photo2shape is set to work, and QGIS is hard to kill. 
On a test of 5 of those photos it runs fine.

Comment: Which QGIS version and photo2shape is used? Maybe, plugin failed to process certain photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, to use the metaphor that we users are merely standing on the shoulders of giants, he has shifted his weight to another foot......

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/geotagphotos/wiki

Works fantastically !

Answer (score 1):

I love the photo2shape plugin in QGIS and I found that it helps to avoid excessively long file paths. I think I ran into the length limit on the number of characters allowed in the 'filepath' field a couple of times. In Ubuntu this doesn't seem to be a problem, but in Windows I recommend creating a special directory for photo folders in the root of drive C:

A shortcut to the new photo folder on the desktop can be convenient.

I have not experienced any more problems in Windows with photo2shape since I started doing things this way.

Comment: I tried your method of putting the folder at the root of the drive, this gave a marginal improvement, the conversion has now progressed a little further but now hangs at 52%. I also took the precaution of removing spaces from the now much shorter filename, but no joy.   My workaround is to use Geosetter to create a kmz, then extract the kml from that.